# Bug with 'parent user' in chat

Tags: bug, chat, account-suspension

When I first joined chat.SE, the 'parent site' was Puzzling.SE. Recently I found I was spending more time in the SciFi chatroom than the Puzzling chatroom, so I changed my 'parent site' to SciFi.SE. This took effect in that e.g. when I set up a new chatroom, it was automatically a SciFi chatroom. But now I've been suspended on Puzzling, and this has also caused me to be suspended in chat, supposedly because 'my account is suspended on the parent site' - but the parent site is SciFi and I'm not suspended there!

Any idea why this might be? Is it a bug in the system? It's quite annoying that I can participate on the main SciFi site but not in SciFi chat, even though my 'chat parent' is SciFi.

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Comment: When exactly did you change your parent user? This doesn't work retroactively after you were suspended, the parent user at the moment of suspension is the important part.

Comment: @MadScientist I changed it a few days ago, and was suspended just after midnight today (lovely New Year's present :-p )

Answer (score 4):

Main site suspensions propagating to chat work by checking to see whether a chat account's parent user is suspended. If so, a *separate* chat suspension is put into place (with the "suspended on the parent site" reason) for a duration of the remainder of the main-site suspension. The two suspensions are from then on not linked in any way.

Hence, the reason you are chat-suspended on chat.SE is because your parent site was changed to Puzzling some time during your suspension on Puzzling proper. Changing it back to Scifi or to any other site will then have no effect, as the chat suspension is no longer linked to the main site suspension.

Comment: I didn't change my parent site to Puzzling at any time during my suspension, so if you're right that it 'was changed', then someone else must have changed it. Is that possible? Was it you, since you were the one who suspended me? If that's not possible, then your answer must be incorrect. As I told MadScientist above, I changed my parent site to SciFi well *before* being suspended.

Comment: Another question: why was I suspended on Puzzling for remarks I made in a Meta chatroom? Is that within the rules?

Comment: @randal'thor Yes, it is possible for someone else to change your parent site. Reasons for suspensions typically remain confidential, but if you'd like to shame yourself in public by all means feel free...

Comment: So did you change my parent site just to ensure I was suspended on chat? Or do you decline to comment on the matter? It seems a very strange and inappropriate thing to do. If you want to suspend me on Puzzling but not on SciFi, why should you care if I talk to people in Mos Eisley?

Comment: And yes, I think I will publicise the reasons you gave for my suspension, since I believe it was completely unjustified. I note you still haven't replied to my PM.

Comment: @rand you might have better luck contacting the team directly if you want to appeal the suspension. (email or submit "contact us" form)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for this! I'm just worried that they get loads of "I shouldn't have been suspended" spam from people who really should, and will just ignore it. Do suspension appeals ever get granted? And what email address should I write to?

Comment: @Doorknob冰 Would you mind editing your answer in order to make clear that *someone else (not me)* changed my parent site, *within seconds of my suspension* (I was in a SciFi chatroom at the time, so I know this), and then changed it back again? Then I'll accept your answer and we can clear out some of these comments. Thanks!

Comment: @rand just click the "contact us" link in the footer, choose "other" and pledge your case. I'm quite sure they are used to get tons of rants and learned by now to identify cases worth responding to. Can't promise anything, just advise you to be patient, especially now having holidays.